# Conditionally adding multiple classes in a ternary using React's className attribute with PostCSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ternary-operator, postcss

I'm using PostCSS with React and wanted to add a regular class and modifier class based on my component's state. In short I'd like to perform a show/hide toggle based on the presence/absence of a search input query. Unfortunately it appears that using bracket notation is just rendering the class names in a way that they're unrecognizable.

```
className={ this.state.suggestionsAvailable ? styles['site-search__suggestions'] styles['site-search__suggestions--active'] : styles['site-search__suggestions'] }>
```

Has anyone encountered this with a workaround?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './SiteSearch.css';

class SiteSearch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      suggestions: [],
      suggestionsAvailable: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        ...
        <div className={ this.state.suggestionsAvailable ? styles['site-search__suggestions'] styles['site-search__suggestions--active'] : styles['site-search__suggestions'] }>
         ...
       </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
.site-search__suggestions {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e3e5;
  height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.site-search__suggestions--active {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: `<div className={ this.state.suggestionsAvailable ? styles['site-search__suggestions'] : styles['site-search__suggestions'] }>` does that line work? (i.e. only applying one style)

Comment: Yes but check out how my modifier class is setup. Doing it the way you've described would require me to copy all the styling from the base class.

Comment: if it works with only one style like my example there, then this might do the trick:  `<div className={ this.state.suggestionsAvailable ? styles['site-search__suggestions'] + " " + styles['site-search__suggestions--active'] : styles['site-search__suggestions'] }>` tell me if it works and I'll leave it as an answer. When it's parsing your solution I don't think it knows what to do when there is space between the styles like that

Comment: Yes, that works! You inspired me to go a step further and discover that this can also be done using ES2015 template literals as well: `${styles['site-search__suggestions'] styles['site-search__suggestions--active']}`. Both sound solutions nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div className={ this.state.suggestionsAvailable ? styles['site-search__suggestions'] + " " + styles['site-search__suggestions--active'] : styles['site-search__suggestions'] }>
```

Is what's needed for this to work, the strings have to be concatenated to show up properly.

@Carl Edwards also had a solution for ES2015 that uses a template literal:

```
${styles['site-search__suggestions']} ${styles['site-search__suggestions--active']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy.

Comment: One additional note for the template literals. I had to separately enclose each class in their own set of brackets for this to work: `${styles['site-search__suggestions']} ${styles['site-search__suggestions--active']}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use *.join(' ')*.

To join more than one substring, you need to make **array[ ]**.

```
<div className={ this.state.suggestionsAvailable ? [styles['site-search__suggestions'],styles['site-search__suggestions--active']].join(' ') : styles['site-search__suggestions'] }>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Object.assign to combine multiple objects into one new Object

```
Object.assign{{},styles['site-search__suggestions'],styles['site-search__suggestions--active'] }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign